# install erlang with asdf without jinterface

Tags: java, erlang, elixir, javac, asdf-vm

I'm trying to install Erlang (and later Elixir) with asdf however I'm getting an error regarding `jinterface` as the install process seems to freeze:

```
➜  ~ asdf install erlang 22.1.1
Downloading OTP-22.1.1.tar.gz to /Users/me/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/archives
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   122    0   122    0     0    320      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   321
100 52.4M    0 52.4M    0     0  7604k      0 --:--:--  0:00:07 --:--:-- 9203k
Extracting source code
Building Erlang/OTP 22.1.1 (asdf_22.1.1), please wait...
APPLICATIONS DISABLED (See: /Users/me/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/builds/asdf_22.1.1/otp_build_22.1.1.log)
 * jinterface     : Java compiler disabled by user

DOCUMENTATION INFORMATION (See: /Users/me/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/builds/asdf_22.1.1/otp_build_22.1.1.log)
 * documentation  :
 *                  fop is missing.
 *                  Using fakefop to generate placeholder PDF files.
```

I had a look at `https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang` and it says

```
For example, to skip the java dependency during installation use:
$ export KERL_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS="--disable-debug --without-javac"
$ asdf install erlang <version>
```

If I had to guess, this is a java issue so when I try this solution it doesn't work and I get the same output.

Any idea on how to install Erlang this without installing Java? I don't recall this being an issue with Homebrew, meaning Homebrew requiring Java compiler present.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect it's not actually freezing - it's compiling Erlang, but hiding all the output.  Give it ten to twenty minutes or so, and it should complete.

You can verify this with `top`. Compiling Erlang is CPU intensive, so you should be able to easily spot C and Erlang compilers with close to 100% CPU usage.

Answer (score 3):

you can track progress with

`tail -f /Users/me/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/builds/asdf_22.1.1/otp_build_22.1.1.log`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying it without jinterface you can install all dependencies.This fix I found [here](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang/issues/83) it works

```
sudo apt-get install automake autoconf libreadline-dev libncurses-dev \
libssl-dev libyaml-dev libxslt-dev libffi-dev libtool unixodbc-dev \
libwxgtk3.0-dev libgl1-mesa-dev  libglu1-mesa-dev libssh-dev xsltproc fop \
libxml2-utils
```

In case you are installing on small server like 1GB memory, if compiling fails [increasing swap memory](https://linuxhandbook.com/increase-swap-ubuntu/) helps, took a while for me to fix.

Comment: The [asdf-erlang documentation](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang/blob/master/README.md#ubuntu-and-debian) has an up-to date list of recommended  dependencies.